# Why do fonts look weird on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've got a problem in which some websites don't display correctly in Chrome:

[[image]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJjgL.png)

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with Google Chrome.  I personally don't use Chrome unless I am checking my website for compatibility.  Below is a Google Chrome support answer for this very thing.  Go ahead and try this, if it does not work, report back and I will help you further.

[Google Chrome Answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en)

--Edit--

I cannot see the picture btw, it's too small, and does not allow me view a larger version.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hJjgL.png

Comment: Thanks MrJustin! The solution in the link you provided works. (In my case, it was Helvetica, not Helvetica Neue.)

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help.  :)